# Проблема с двумерным массивом в рекурсивной функции C

Tags: c, массивы, функции, рекурсия

Имеются две рекурсивные функции rec_matrix_zero и rec_matrix_print, отвечающие за обнуление двумерного массива и его вывод в консоль соответственно.

```
#define dim 70

void rec_matrix_zerro(int(*arr)[dim], int i, int j) {
    if ((i == dim) && (j == dim)) *(*(arr + i) + j) = 0; //end
    else {
        if (j < dim) { //not end of a line
            *(*(arr + i) + j) = 0;
            rec_matrix_zerro(arr, i, j + 1); 

        }
        else { //end of a line
            *(*(arr + i) + j) = 0;
            rec_matrix_zerro(arr, i+1, 0);

        }
    }


}
void rec_matrix_print(int(*arr)[dim], int i, int j) {
    if ((i == dim) && (j == dim)) printf("%i", *(*(arr + i) + j)); //end
    else {
        if (j <dim) { //not end of a line
            printf("%i", *(*(arr + i) + j));
            rec_matrix_print(arr, i, j + 1);

        }
        else { //end of a line
            printf("%i", *(*(arr + i) + j));
            printf("\n");
            rec_matrix_print(arr, i + 1, 0);

        }
    }


}
```

При значении размера массивов **dim<65** не возникает никаких проблем, но при больших размерах массивов возникает непонятная мне, как новичку в c, ошибка, связанная, кажется, с выделением памяти.

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int A[dim][dim], B[dim][dim];
    int(*p_arrA)[dim];
    int(*p_arrB)[dim];
    p_arrA = A;
    p_arrB = B;
    rec_matrix_zerro(p_arrA, 0, 0);
    rec_matrix_print(p_arrA, 0, 0);




    scanf("%i", &i);
}
```

[image: Ошибка]

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00361879 в Project17.exe:
>   0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (параметры: 0x00000001, 0x00A02F90).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема и что с этим делать?

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема не с выделением памяти, а с выходом за границы массива. Прогоните программу под отладчиком.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: `if ((i == dim) && (j == dim)) *(*(arr + i) + j) = 0;` - Как минимум явный выход за границу...